# Does C++ have a way to ignore an exception from a function?

Tags: c++, exception

I created a function that throws an exception, but under some circumstances I want it to simply ignore this exception.

I wrote my code like this, but it's not quite elegant:

```
try {
    myFunction();
} catch (...) {}
```

Does C++ another way to write this?

Comment: No, there isn't sadly. but you might want to rethink your design if you want to ignore an "exceptional case"

Comment: If you want to ignore an error condition "under some circumstances", then the function throwing an exception is a poor design decision.   Better to return some error indication that can be ignored.

Comment: You can provide two versions of the function, one which throws when there's a problem, and one of which returns an indication of success or failure. (And write the first in terms of the second - not vice versa.)

Comment: I don't agree with you Peter. My functions is a good example of this. I need the throw in 99% of cases.
However, I have a little procedure that I don't know the data source and the procedure can try to process it. If the data is not what it expected I can ignore it.
I will lost performance if include a procedure to validate the data then the best option is just ignore the throw.

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't.

you can follow what the standard does in this case which is to overload the function twice, once with [std::nothrow_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow_t) and once without. use the later to wrap the first

```
std::error_code my_function(std::nothrow_t) noexcept;
void my_function(); //throws
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that is how you would write it.

It's not bad in and of itself, though if you find that your code is becoming ugly due to the number of times you're employing this construct, that may be a signal that you're employing it too much.

I find myself ignoring exceptions occasionally, but if it's the "norm" for you then something may be wrong with your design.

Comment: It is not a common case,  but this kind of line bother me. I thought to pass to  function a boolean to set when throw it but I think this kind of solution is worst and I prefer the fry catch way.

Comment: @MenasheRosemberg: Well, it's your choice, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can write inhibiting wrapper template method like this:

```c++
#include <utility>

template< typename Callable, typename... Arguments > void
Ingnore_Exceptions(Callable && method, Arguments && ... arguments) noexcept
{
    try
    {
        method(::std::forward< Arguments >(arguments)...);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //  Do nothing.
    }
}

void
May_Throw(int, char const *)
{
    throw(-1);
}

int
main(int, char**)
{
    Ingnore_Exceptions(May_Throw, 42, "whatever");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why is `method` taken by rvalue reference but `arguments` is not? Why `main(void)`? Why `return(0)`?

Comment: Alright, it makes sense to forward arguments as well. `main` is not really relevant in this example, but I've corrected it too. And what is wrong with `return(0)`?

Comment: `main()` would also be acceptable C++. The parentheses are useless; `return 0` is just as good, but `return 0` is implied from `main`, so you can just omit it entirely. Taking forwarding references is mildly unnecessary if you don't actually forward.

Comment: I wish they thought more about parentheses when designing C++... And the rule for omitting return in main being OK is a total abomination.

Comment: @VTT, [It's not just C++](http://ideone.com/koXLbx). That's a natural consequence of a parenthesized expression also being an expression and it's what lets you do `2 * (1 + 3)`.

Comment: Actually I would prefer parentheses to be used only to contain method arguments. And scope after branching to be mandatory (this is actually a one of C language design's epic failures). And a strict left-to-right ordering. But those are not going to happen anyway, and I'm really getting off-topic...

Comment: @VTT So in your preferred language, you'd write `return 0;` rather than `return(0);`? Then I really don't understand leaving it the way it is in your answer.

Comment: Of course I can write `return 0;` and `throw -1;` but I still write `return(0);` and `throw(-1);` so they are consistent with other similar constructs that require parentheses, such as `if`, `for`, `switch`, `catch`, `noexcept` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it would be

```
try 
{
  MyFunction () ;
}
catch (ExpectedExceptionType &e)
{
  // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: How so? This is functionally identical, and adds nothing.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition This changes `...` to `ExpectedExceptionType &`, to prevent exceptions getting caught that shouldn't be. But that isn't obvious from the answer, and an explanation would certainly be a good improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using below macro:

```
#define IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS(stmt) \
try {                           \
  stmt                          \
} catch (...) {                 \
}
```

You can pass statements to the macro like:

```
IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS(delta();
                  gamma();)
```

Above macro expands to:

```
try { delta();gamma(); } catch (...) { }
```

If you want to use variables in try block you have to declare them before calling the macro:

```
double res = 0.0;
IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS(res = delta();)
// Use res variable here. Do not forget res variable may not be changed in try block
```

Comment: i am willing to place a bet that it is only a matter of time before this macro bites you...

i strongly dislike using the c preprocessor like this. of the top of my head (only seeing this code snipet) I can propose an implementation taking lambda arguments or even simply writing the try/catch manually every time

Answer (score -1):

We can,t ignore the exception directly. If u want ignore the exception

```
try
{
   myFunction();
}
catch(Exception)
{}
```

It will catch all the exception and doe not do anything due to empty catch block and your condition of ignore is satisfied.

Comment: Yeah, so, that's exactly what the OP is already doing. So you taught nothing.